# How to set Bytes data in firebase using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The Cloud FireStore supports Bytes datatype, but failed to give an example of how to setting it,
i am trying to upload a thumbnail image as bytes to the FireStore, in Flutter.
Can someone give an example how to do it?

```
File imageFile;
final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
    await databaseReference
        .collection("Users")
        .document('${user.strId}')
        .setData({'thumbnailPhoto': ???}); // how to convert imageFile to Bytes?
```

**EDIT**
I think both of the answers posted by Richard Heap and Jay Vasan work, using `blob` or `base64Encode` actually give the same value in FireStore under key `thumbnailPhoto`. I decide to give the bounty to Richard since it hides the details of the internal binary coding.

Comment: `await file.readAsBytes()`

Comment: This doesn't work as it throws an error `PlatformException(error, Could not serialize object. Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cloud Firestore raw bytes is represented by `Blob` in Dart, so use:

```
    .setData({'thumbnailPhoto', Blob(await file.readAsBytes())});
```

When you read this back from Cloud Firestore you'll get back a `Blob`. Access its bytes with `blob.bytes`. For example, to write to a file use:

```
  await file.writeAsBytes(theBlob.bytes); // overwrite or create the file
```

Comment: can you give an example how to construct file from blob?

Comment: Until yesterday I got back a Blob as you mention in the post. Today I upgraded to cloud_firestore 4.7.0. Since then I seem to be getting List<dynamic> instead, containing elements of <int>. I also upgraded to Dart 3.0 at the same time. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can convert the image to base64 string.

open image as:

```
var imageFile = File(imagePath);
```

convert to base64:

```
String base64Image = base64Encode(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
```